# How to create a looping image scroller effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css-animations

I'm trying to work out a client side solution for an looping image scroll using jQuery. The center div contains 4 images which will move to the right. As the furthest right image leaves the page, it is added to the beginning of the div so it scrolls around again.

I'm not explaining it very well so I made a diagram:

[image: Diagram]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would highly recommend using a jQuery plugin like the following: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#demos - I only say this because you mentioned jQuery. The slick slider is simple to implement and does exactly what you ask.

Comment: as an aside, awesome pictures of cats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple proof of concept that I whipped up. It's a little bit unstable (a lot of guesswork with the scroll numbers was involved), but it should be what you're looking for, and it doesn't require any plugins or additional libraries.

```
function scroller () {
    padding = 5;
    border = 1;
    $(".item").first().insertAfter($(".item").last());
    $(".gallery").animate({scrollLeft: $(".item").first().outerWidth() + padding + border, easing: 'swing'}, 1200, function(){
        $(".gallery").scrollLeft(1);
        scroller();
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/L8L4e2eg/

---

EDIT:

I couldn't manage to make the animation completely smooth using jQuery, so I found and modified an [existing infinite scroller](https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/) created solely with CSS using the `animation` and `keyframes` attributes. Just like my previous example in jQuery, it requires some fine tuning in order to get make it look completely right, but it pays off in the end.

```
@-webkit-keyframes moveSlideshow {
    0% { left: 0; }
    100% { left: -635px; }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/hrcekoha/3/

Comment: Just what I'm looking for, thanks. Is there any way to smooth the infinite scrollLeft? I've tried a linear ease however it's still a bit stop and start http://jsfiddle.net/L8L4e2eg/2/

Comment: @bengem I found a code example that accomplished more-or-less what you wanted using CSS. I modified it a bit in order to make it look the same as the jQuery example (but with completely smooth scrolling). I updated my answer with a quick desciption, code example, and link to a new JSFiddle. Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before. The easiest way to go about this is to do:

```
var nextImage = function() {
    $('#container').children().last().insertBefore(
        $('#container').children().first();
    )
}
```

Or if you add a class to each image you can do:

```
var nextImage = function() {
    $('img.slider:last').insertBefore($('img.slider:first'));
}
```

Then set an interval:

```
window.sliderInterval = setInterval(function(){ nextImage(); }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment above recommending to use the Slick jQuery plugin (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) I've created a fiddle for you. http://jsfiddle.net/4ydy7ooz/

```
$('.multiple-items').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

Code above so the fiddle is linked.

Comment: Wow, mobile Safari *really* does not like that plugin. All of the images start slightly stretching and continuously flashing after you tap the "next" button in your demo only once.